# How to set "attr" binding element to not true?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I would like to know if it is possible to define a value that is not true in an attribute in this way.

```html
<div data-bind="visible:isActive, attr: { 'aria-hidden': !isActive() })">
   { Content }
</div>
```

This does not work in my case.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `|| undefined`.

Like:

```html
<div 
  data-bind="visible:isActive, attr: { 'aria-hidden': !isActive() || undefined })">
   { Content }
</div>
```

You can rewrite `!isActive() || undefined` to `isActive() ? undefined : true` if you like it more.

Also, if `isActive` is an observable, you do not need the `()` in `isActive()`.